# Select which nth child is the element from javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was just wondering if there is a way to do the following.
i have a page with the following html code.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="tab"></div>
 <div class="tab"></div>
 <div class="tab"></div>
</div>
```

and i have a script code that will check which tab is clicked.

```
$(function(){

$('body').on('click','.tab',function(){ 
// check which tab is clicked
//do something });

});
```

what i want to do is to  **get what which child of the container is clicked**. 
Suppose i click on second tab, can i know which child is clicked. if tab 2 is clicked i want to do something, if tab 3 is clicked i want to do something else.

Comment: try `$(this).index()`

Comment: @KamranAhmed, why you remove your answer? separate events is a good idea

Comment: I was updating it, so removed it for a while to avoid downvotes. Actually, it would be a bad idea. How about, if you don't know the exact number of tabs, or if they are being generated dynamically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `index()` method:

```
$('body').on('click','.tab',function(){ 
     var tabIdx = $(this).index() + 1;

     switch (tabIdx)
     {
         case 1:
             // do something for 1
             break;
         case 2:
             // do something for 2
             break;
         case 3:
             // do something for 3
             break;
     }
});
```

See [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/index/

```
$(".tab").click(function() { 
    console.log($(this).index());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with `index()`, which returns the zero-based index of the element from amongst its sibling elements:

```
$('body').on('click','.tab',function(){ 
    var clicked = $(this).index();
    switch (clicked) {
        // if the index is 0, call functionOne():
        case 0:
            functionOne();
            break;
        // if the index is 0, call functionTwo():
        case 1:
            functionTwo();
            break;
        // if the index is is not identified,
        // use the default, and call functionDefault():
        default:
            functionDefault();
            break;
    }
});
```

References:

- [`index()`](http://api.jQuery.com/index/).

Answer (score 1):

You may use the index method to get the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) of the clicked element and then

```
$(document).on('click', '.tab', function(){
   var tabNum = $(this).index(); // 0 based index of the tab
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/d4c2wr2v/)

Answer (score 1):

Hi the below code can help

```
$(".tab").click(function() { 
  alert($(this).index());
 });
```

It works i think.